# How can I login to my local drupal site 8.3.1 which was under maintence mode

Tags: users, maintenance-mode

I just logout to see what will the home page look like. Now, I can't login into my local site.

Comment: You can go to /user if logging in is allowed, or use drush with drush uli to auto login as user 1 to view the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to login by enter below url.

```
http://example.com/?q=admin
or
http://example.com/user
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to /user/login, it works even in maintenance mode, and then sign in as an admin.